# How can I send a message to a custom Google Cast Receiver from Chrome for iOS?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast

I'm using the [CastHelloText-chrome](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-chrome) example and am able to get it all working just fine from the Chrome browser on my desktop, however, when I try to use Chrome on my iOS device, I receive the following error when trying to create a session:

> { "code": "channel_error", "description": "The operation couldn't be completed. (com.google.chrome.ios.cast error 2.)" }

This error happens when executing the following:

```
chrome.cast.requestSession(function(e) {
    session = e;
    session.sendMessage(namespace, message, onSuccess.bind(this, "Message sent: " + message), onError);
  }, onError);
```

Specifically, this seems to happen on the `requestSession` function call (the nested callback never actually executes).

Everything up until this point seems to work.  In fact, on my iOS device, I even receive the popup asking where to cast to (Chromecast) and once I select it, my Chromecast does indeed display my custom receiver.  However, I still receive that error message and never get a session object, so I can't send messages to the receiver.

Like I said, this seems to work fine on my desktop Chrome browser, but does not work on my iOS Chrome browser.  Does this sample not work on iOS devices?  Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome on desktop and Chrome on mobile are not the same. You need to use the [iOS API](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/). Use the sample app for [CastHelloText-ios](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-ios) as a reference.

Comment: That requires that I create an iOS app, doesn't it?  That is exactly what I *don't* want to do.  All I'm trying to do is get a Chromecast to display one simple HTML page from any device (iPhone, iPad, Android phone, Android tablet, OSX, Windows, etc.)  If I have to create separate apps for every platform, I'll probably have to not use Chromecast.

Comment: Additionally, I refuse to believe it's impossible since I've clearly been able to get my iOS device to connect to my Chromecast and actually initialize my custom receiver.  It just errors when I create a session.

Comment: Currently you cannot universally rely on Chrome on mobile platforms to do what you want (i.e. act as a sender that you can write an app against).

Comment: @AliNaddaf - Thanks, but I guess I don't understand.  Is the API just half baked?  Why am I able to initialize my custom receiver from Chrome on mobile, but not send messages to it?  Is this functionality just not yet completed?  Does your team intend to finish this at some point?  Is there some way for me to initialize the receiver and send some chunk of data along with my initialization request?  I really only need to send an arbitrary string to it upon startup and then never need to communicate with it again, so I don't need full messaging services.

Comment: Chrome on desktop requires the Cast Extensions to be able to support cast and lack of such mechanism on mobile platforms make it more complicated but that is something that the team is aware of and working on. At this point, your best approach is to use a native client with iOS SDK or Android SDK. See https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=418 as well