# Chromecast API Sender - Android Phone

Tags: android, chromecast

I have tried to write some webapps for chromecast to cast my own website to the chromecast. Everthing is great on chrome desktop. I am able to connect to chromecast send messages and ...

But when I load the website from a chrome browser on phone, it keeps saying connect to chromecast everytime when I want to send a message to my receiver.

I do not want to write an app for the phones and want to keep it on webapp.

This was a sample code from SDK Developer.

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var applicationID = 'HIDDEN';
var namespace = 'urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.test';
var session = null;
var sessionID = null;

/**
 * Call initialization for Cast
 */
if (!chrome.cast || !chrome.cast.isAvailable) {
    setTimeout(initializeCastApi, 1000);
}

/**
 * initialization
 */
function initializeCastApi() {
    var sessionRequest = new chrome.cast.SessionRequest(applicationID);
    var apiConfig = new chrome.cast.ApiConfig(sessionRequest,
        sessionListener,
        receiverListener);

    chrome.cast.initialize(apiConfig, onInitSuccess, onError);
};

/**
 * initialization success callback
 */
function onInitSuccess() {
    appendMessage("onInitSuccess");
}

/**
 * initialization error callback
 */
function onError(message) {
    appendMessage("onError: "+JSON.stringify(message));
}

/**
 * generic success callback
 */
function onSuccess(message) {
    appendMessage("onSuccess: "+message);
}

/**
 * callback on success for stopping app
 */
function onStopAppSuccess() {
    appendMessage('onStopAppSuccess');
}

/**
 * session listener during initialization
 */
function sessionListener(e) {
    appendMessage('New session ID:' + e.sessionId);
    session = e;
    session.addUpdateListener(sessionUpdateListener);  
    session.addMessageListener(namespace, receiverMessage);
    sessionID = session.sessionId;
}

/**
 * listener for session updates
 */
function sessionUpdateListener(isAlive) {
  var message = isAlive ? 'Session Updated' : 'Session Removed';
  message += ': ' + session.sessionId;
  appendMessage(message);

  if (!isAlive) {
    session = null;
  }
};

/**
 * utility function to log messages from the receiver
 * @param {string} namespace The namespace of the message
 * @param {string} message A message string
 */
function receiverMessage(namespace, message) {
  appendMessage("receiverMessage: "+namespace+", "+message);
};

/**
 * receiver listener during initialization
 */
function receiverListener(e) {
  if( e === 'available' ) {
    appendMessage("receiver found");
   // load();
  }
  else {
    appendMessage("receiver list empty");
  }
}

/**
 * stop app/session
 */
function stopApp() {
  session.stop(onStopAppSuccess, onError);
}

/**
 * send a message to the receiver using the custom namespace
 * receiver CastMessageBus message handler will be invoked
 * @param {string} message A message string
 */
function sendMessage(message) {
  if (session!=null) {
    session.sendMessage(namespace, message, onSuccess.bind(this, "Message sent: " + message), onError);
  }
  else {
    chrome.cast.requestSession(function(e) {
        session = e;
        session.sendMessage(namespace, message, onSuccess.bind(this, "Message sent: " + message), onError);
      }, onError);
  }
}

/**
 * append message to debug message window
 * @param {string} message A message string
 */
function appendMessage(message) {
  console.log(message);
//    var dw = document.getElementById("debugmessage");
//    dw.innerHTML += '\n' + JSON.stringify(message);
};

/**
 * utility function to handle text typed in by user in the input field
 */
function update() {
  sendMessage(document.getElementById("input").value);
}

/**
 * handler for the transcribed text from the speech input
 * @param {string} words A transcibed speech string
 */
function transcribe(words) {
    sendMessage(words);
}

</script>

</head>
```

I call function transcribe and it sends messages to chrome receiver which I wrote. It works perfectly on desktop version. But on Phone it keeps saying connect to chrome cast.

Does anybody know if there is anything for be force set for working on phone?

Comment: I know that many of you will tell me that the cast from desktop and ios are not the same and Ihave to use the IOS API. and this is the sample : https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-ios

However I do not want to create an app, I only want to use my webapp on desktp and as well on any phones, tablets, ...

So what would be the way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I have researched more and more and found some other threads here on Stackflow regarding this issue.

[How can I send a message to a custom Google Cast Receiver from Chrome for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160320/how-can-i-send-a-message-to-a-custom-google-cast-receiver-from-chrome-for-ios)

It seems it is not possible to do as it is not integrated to the chrome on phones.

However does anyone know if chromecats support other ways to communicate btw. sender and receiver?